# viewing data from Exceptions in ExceptionTelemetry

Tags: azure-application-insights

After logging ExceptionTelemetry, is there a way to see the Exception.Data content in the logs?  I am using Exception.Data to capture informative data about the environment when the exception occured.

It appears that ExceptionTelemetry has its own kvp for properties and metrics.

If not supported, then the plan is to wrap ExceptionTelemetry in code that walk through the exception/innerexception tree and add any data KVP entries it finds to these dictionaries.  I was hoping not to have to do that myself...

Answer (score 1):

the AI sdk does not walk through the `Exception.Data` structure itself.  the items in exception data could be any type, complex structures, etc, and could literally contain *anything*.

The AI SDK allows you to send custom properties (strings), of limited size and custom metrics (doubles).  There are also some limitations on the number of distinctly named properties for the lifetime of the AI application (though these limitations are always changing).

So you might not want to walk through and send *ALL* data in exception data, you might want to grab only the things you know you'll need, in order not waste custom properties?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - will do as suggested.  We can tag our own data and pick it up at the top level catch handler which should optimize usefulness vs size.